# How to select unique JSON objects from Identical JSON array with JQ

Tags: jq

Below is the input JSON:

```
{
  "sn": "fdd",
 
  "sc": [
    {
      "pn": "di",
      "pv": {
        "val": "26",
        "com": "="
      },
      "fix": "Hello",
      "tp": "String"
    },
    {
      "pn": "di2",
      "pv": {
        "val": "28",
        "com": "="
      },
      "fix": "Hello2",
      "tp": "String"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the JQ Command I have tried which is generating identical objects:

```
def getWhereVal(input):
[input.sc[]] | unique;
def getPreVal(input):
input.sc[].fix;
. as $input | getPreVal($input) as $preVal | getWhereVal($input)
```

I am getting below output from above JQ command:

```
[
  {
    "pn": "di",
    "pv": {
      "val": "26",
      "com": "="
    },
    "fix": "Hello",
    "tp": "String"
  },
  {
    "pn": "di2",
    "pv": {
      "val": "28",
      "com": "="
    },
    "fix": "Hello2",
    "tp": "String"
  }
]
[
  {
    "pn": "di",
    "pv": {
      "val": "26",
      "com": "="
    },
    "fix": "Hello",
    "tp": "String"
  },
  {
    "pn": "di2",
    "pv": {
      "val": "28",
      "com": "="
    },
    "fix": "Hello2",
    "tp": "String"
  }
]
```

I aim to retrieve a distinct object from a set of identical objects, as illustrated below:

```
{
    "pn": "di",
    "pv": {
      "val": "26",
      "com": "="
    },
    "fix": "Hello",
    "tp": "String"
  },
  {
    "pn": "di2",
    "pv": {
      "val": "28",
      "com": "="
    },
    "fix": "Hello2",
    "tp": "String"
  }
```

Can someone please help me to get desired output, I am not able to get result using unique function.

Comment: Don't agree with the close vote reason. That basically means `jq` tag should be non-existent in SO. jq is a Turing complete language on its own to manipulate JSON

Comment: The question is not clear. What is the constraint for getting the objects unique?

Comment: I second Inian's opinion on the close vote as well as the lacking clarity of the question. That said, to get a stream of unique objects from the `.sc` array, simply run `.sc | unique[]` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Xpe-YXEJiC1)). If you want to apply some constraints, use `unique_by(…)` instead of `unique`.

Comment: I am not able to use unique because I have two different arrays. unique is applicable only for single array. In my provided jq command, getPreVal() function is returning two rows as sc array present in input, having two json objects & because of that when I am passing $input value to getWhereVal function, it is returning input two times. If you will paste given inputs and JQ commands to JQ playground, it will be more clear what I am trying achieve.